# How can i Auto-resize the text of a TextBlock or a TextBox when Content Size Changes in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can i Auto-resize the text of a TextBlock or a TextBox when Content Size Changes in c#.
i'm trying to develop an app for windows phone 8.1 with the help of 8.1 SDK in visual studio! i want my TextBlock to function as it functions in the in-built WP8.1 Calculator app! as the input numbers increase, the size of the text decreases!
please anyone provide the possible solution?

Comment: Is a [Viewbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) available for windows phone?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the code below should help you.

```
            int regularSize = 8;
            int newSize = regularSize;
            int textBoxWidth = Tb_Filter.Size.Width;
            int textLength = Tb_Filter.Text.Length;
            if ((textLength * regularSize) > textBoxWidth)
            {
                do{
                    newSize -= 1;
                }
                while((textLength * newSize) > textBoxWidth);
            }

            Tb_Filter.Font = new Font(Tb_Filter.Font.FontFamily, newSize);
```

You may want to modify it to take into account the space between characters as well.